# Dismiss sheet SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a dismiss button for my modal sheet as follows:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Environment(\.isPresented) var present
    var body: some View {
        Button("return") {
            self.present?.value = false
        }
    }
}

struct DataTest : View {
    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var modal: some View {
        TestView()
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button("Present") {
            self.showModal = true
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showModal) {
            self.modal
        }
    }
}
```

But the return button when tapped does nothing. When the modal is displayed the following appears in the console:

> [WindowServer] display_timer_callback: unexpected state (now:5fbd2efe5da4 < expected:5fbd2ff58e89)

If you force unwrap `present` you find that it is `nil`

How can I dismiss `.sheet` programmatically?

Comment: Starting from iOS 15 we can use `DismissAction` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68009068/8697793).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For me, beta 4 broke this method - using the Environment variable `isPresented` - of using a dismiss button. Here's what I do nowadays:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingModal = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
           self.showingModal.toggle()
        }) {
           Text("Show Modal")
        }
        .sheet(
            isPresented: $showingModal,
            content: { ModalPopup(showingModal: self.$showingModal) }
        )
    }
}
```

And in your modal view:

```
struct ModalPopup : View {
    @Binding var showingModal:Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingModal = false
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss").frame(height: 60)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to go currently. isPresented will only work if you use it with the deprecated PresentationLink but only if it is not used as a navigationBar item.

Comment: @Marc_T., I've mentioned this once before here and the reply was the same amount of frustration as I - why the changes? (I'm clearly not part of the Swift Evolution - hope I said ti right.) Beta 2 == `PresentationButton`. Beta 3 == `PresentationLink`. Beta 4 == um, sorry, it's all deprecated and" you're screwed"? Do you have a link as to *why* this sort of thing is going on? Trust me, I understand betas. Understand we're also talking version one as in `Swift 1.0`. Maybe I'm just a bit naive as to the politics behind something like this - but I'm intelligent. And would love to know what's up.

Answer (score 49):

### iOS 15+

Starting from iOS 15 we can use [DismissAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dismissaction) that can be accessed as `@Environment(\.dismiss)`.

*There's no more need to use `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`.*

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sheet")
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Done") {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Use `presentationMode` from the `@Environment`.

> Beta 6

```
struct SomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Ohay!")
            Button("Close") {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. Could you please explain more or add more code.

Comment: One annoying thing about both the methods of dismissing a sheet (this one, and injecting an isShowing binding), is that the `onDismiss` closure of the sheet method doesn't fire when you tap the dismiss button. But it will fire if the user dismisses the modal by swiping down. Might raise this with Apple as a bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work for macOS navigation views, where both list and view are shown simultaneously. Any known approach for this?

Comment: Since `presentationMode` is a path to a binding, you can actually nest an `@Binding` inside the `@Environment` to get rid of the `.wrappedValue` part.

Comment: This one doesn't work when a NavigationView is used in the sheet. dismiss() pops the navigation view. It doesn't dismiss the sheet.

Answer (score 5):

Apple recommend (in [WWDC 2020 Data Essentials in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040/)) using `@State` and `@Binding` for this. They also place the `isEditorPresented` boolean and the sheet's data in the same `EditorConfig` struct that is declared using @State so it can be mutated, as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
}

struct EditorConfig {
    var isEditorPresented = false
    var title = ""
    var needsSave = false
    
    mutating func present() {
        isEditorPresented = true
        title = ""
        needsSave = false
    }
    
    mutating func dismiss(save: Bool = false) {
        isEditorPresented = false
        needsSave = save
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var items = [Item]()
    @State private var editorConfig = EditorConfig()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.title)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Items")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button(action: presentEditor) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $editorConfig.isEditorPresented, onDismiss: {
                if(editorConfig.needsSave) {
                    items.append(Item(title: editorConfig.title))
                }
            }) {
                EditorView(editorConfig: $editorConfig)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func presentEditor() {
        editorConfig.present()
    }
}

struct EditorView: View {
    @Binding var editorConfig: EditorConfig
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                TextField("Title", text:$editorConfig.title)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                    Button(action: save) {
                        Text("Save")
                    }
                    .disabled(editorConfig.title.count == 0)
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                    Button(action: dismiss) {
                        Text("Dismiss")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func save() {
        editorConfig.dismiss(save: true)
    }
    
    func dismiss() {
        editorConfig.dismiss()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(items: [Item(title: "Banana"), Item(title: "Orange")])
    }
}
```