# SwiftUI: Can only Edit the first item in a ForEach List

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list of bookmarks saved in Core Data. When i try to click on the edit button for a particular bookmark, only the values of the first bookmark on the list will fill up the textfields in the editing sheet no matter which bookmark i pick.

This is a macOS 10.15 app.

ContentView

```
@State private var showEditView = false



ForEach(vm.myBookmarks) { myBookmark in
                      Text(myBookmark.name)
                      Text(myBookmark.url)

                    
                    Button {
                        showEditView = true
                        } label: {
                        Image("pencil")
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showEditView) {
                                          EditBookmarkView(name: myBookmark.name, url: myBookmark.url, isVisible: $showEditView, bm: myBookmark)
                            }
                        }
```

EditBookmarkView

```
struct EditBookmarkView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode)  var presentationMode
    @Binding var isVisible: Bool
    @ObservedObject var vm: EditBookmarkViewModel
    let name: String
    let url: String
    var bm: MyBookmarkViewModel
    
    init(name: String, url: String, isVisible: Binding<Bool>, bm: MyBookmarkViewModel) {
        self.bm = bm
        self.vm = EditBookmarkViewModel(bookmarkVM: bm)
        _isVisible = isVisible
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Edit Name", text: $vm.name)

      
        Spacer()
        TextField("Edit url", text: $vm.url)
            
        Button("Update") {
            vm.save()
            
        }
           
        
      }

   }
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing.
You are passing name and url with your EditBookmarkView Initializer but then you are using a view model in the textfields. Try to do either one or the other.
You should also instantiate the view model in the parent view when using @ObservedObject and not in the init.

Comment: You only have one variable showEditView (common mistake in SwiftUI) . Use .sheet with item argument instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a sheet for each item in `ForEach`, and only one sheet can be represented at a time. So `showEditView` shows the sheet related to the first view in the hierarchy and it in turn captures the first item in your list.

Instead you can you use `sheet` which accepts item binding: sheet is presented when the item is not `nil`. You only need one such sheet, so add it to your list, not to each item.

When you finish editing, set `selectedBookmark` to `nil` to hide the sheet.

Full working example:

```swift
struct Bookmark: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedBookmark: Bookmark?
    let items = (0..<10).map { Bookmark(id: $0) }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(items) { myBookmark in
            HStack {
                Text(String(describing: myBookmark))


                Button {
                    selectedBookmark = myBookmark
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedBookmark) { selectedBookmark in
            let _ = print(String(describing: selectedBookmark))
            Text(String(describing: selectedBookmark))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the sheet to present? Clicking on the button doesn't show the sheet

Comment: @swiftnoob this line `selectedBookmark = myBookmark` should present it

Comment: How does `selectedBookmark` get set back to `nil`?

Comment: @buildsucceeded when user hides the sheet with a swipe, or you hide it programmatically as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233276/dismiss-sheet-swiftui)